# Add and apply a new CSS stylesheet with a button/link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a gallery of items (divs) that float in my page and my main CSS document allows three DIVS to appear side by side before they begin to fill in the next line (I've defined widths in my main CSS). Now I'm trying to create a link that will allow five DIVS to appear side by side. I've created another CSS document (I've included it below the main CSS) that applies different widths to the DIVS and allows more to appear side by side.

What I'm looking for is a JS function that would allow me to toggle between 3 DIVS and 5 DIVS, such as a "zoom in/out" button. However, in my case, it isn't just a matter of changing the width on one class. The button also needs to hide other DIVS within, change font-sizes, etc. I've got the CSS figured out, it works, I'm just looking for a way to load and apply/unapply a CSS document using a function I can activate with a link tag (a).

I have very little JS knowledge, so if you can help me with a function, can you also tell me how to create/activate the button using HTML? (I need to know what to put after the *a href="* )

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

**JS:**

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById('toggle-button').addEventListener('click', toggle_style, false);
}
function toggle_style() {
    if(document.getElementById('dynamic-style').href == window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/style1.css') {
        document.getElementById('dynamic-style').href = 'style2.css';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('dynamic-style').href = 'style1.css';
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="toggle-button" type="button" value="Toggle Style" />
```

To see an example and the full source, see http://shaquin.tk/experiments/togglestyle.html.

Comment: At first I couldn't figure out but I went into the demo source and found the tag on the CSS. This works fantastic! Thanks! Sorry this response is so late.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("a").click(function () {

    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');

  });

});
```